# Kyle model for market-maker price

Tags: market-making, price

Now I make research about market making for cryptocurrency. I’m using model like Avellaneda-Stoikov for optimal control inventory, and I can’t understand how to find S(t) price. Of course, taking the mid-price is not a good idea.
I read a lot about Kyle’s model, and the main thing that I found, is that I need to move orders using trade volume * kyle lambda.
I wrote the script on the python for finding market maker price and as you can see, sometimes a difference between mid-price and generated price is so large.
[image]
My algorithm for generation:
For point in time t: S(0) + (the sum of all market buy order in the range [0:t] - the sum of all market sell order  in the range [0:t]) * Kyle lambda

How I can solve this? Or what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what your questions are, and what the plot shows. 1. S(t) is the normal or lognormal model for the price process assumed. 2. Diff between mid eoidr and generated price is large, you mean generated price is forward looking trying to predict the observed mid?

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz
1. S(t) is the normal
2. I don't want to predict the price. The blue line is mid-price and the orange line is generated. I except that the orange line is will the same as the blue, but smoother, because using Kyle model I 'delete' noise trades

Comment: what do you expect to see? I think your model looks pretty good